# PHP Faking and Following a Form POST from a PHP Page....cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I am creating a checkout process in PHP and have 4 stages/pages. Each page collects different information about the user etc and the 4th stage/page is the secure checkout page which is hosted externally and accepts a POST form submission (from stage 3).

All would be fine however I need to validate the data in stage 3 before I send the user on to the external stage 4 so I looked into this and found this article on cURL...

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html

All looked great but it only seems to post the data to the external 4th page but I need the user to actually be taken there at the same time so they see the 4th page. Ive tried...

```
header('Location: http://externalURLLink');
```

...straight after the cURL connection is closed but it didn't work.

The obvious way is to have a page that basically says "Now click here to go to our secure payment page but I would rather not do that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Make invisible form with required data in the page that you are showing to user and submit it with javascript. There is no other way, except of proxying all requests through your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following function which *may* work for you:

```
function curl_redir_exec($ch,$test = false)
    {
    static $curl_loops = 0;
    static $curl_max_loops = 20;
    if ($curl_loops++>= $curl_max_loops)
    {
    $curl_loops = 0;
    return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    list($header, $data) = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302)
    {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
    $url = @parse_url(trim(array_pop($matches)));
    if (!$url){
        //couldn't process the url to redirect to
        $curl_loops = 0;
        return $data;
    }
    $last_url = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
    if (!$url['scheme'])
    $url['scheme'] = $last_url['scheme'];
    if (!$url['host'])
    $url['host'] = $last_url['host'];
    if (!$url['path'])
        $url['path'] = $last_url['path'];
        $new_url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] . ($url['query']?'?'.$url['query']:'');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url);
        return $this->curl_redir_exec($ch);
    } else {
        $curl_loops=0;
        if($test){
            return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL).'<br />'.$http_code.'<br />'.$data;
        }else{
            return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
$curl_session = curl_init($DESTINATION_URL);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $DESTINATION_URL);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Forwarded-For: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$redirect_url = $shop->curl_redir_exec($curl_session);
if(curl_errno($curl_session))
{
    echo '<p>An error has occurred, please take note of the information below and contact support.</p>';
    echo "<br>Errno : ".curl_errno($curl_session) ."<br>";
    echo "<br>Error : ".curl_error($curl_session) ."<br>";
    die();
}
curl_close($curl_session);
header("location:$redirect_url");
```

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Comment: It will not help user to automatically log in with their browser. He wants to login with php and than let the user to bypass the authentication form in their browser.

Comment: I tried this which takes the user to the same page but it doesn't seem to link them to the posted data. Thanks though.